# Azure Directory Authentication doesn't work when the application is released while it works in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-active-directory, datamart

I have the following connection string to connect to a Datamart server.

```
@"Server=datamartservername; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Encrypt=True; Database=dbname";
```

It works fine when I run the application in Visual Studio. I get the pop up window to authenticate as intended.

However, when I build the installer and release it to other users. The application crashes instead of opening up the pop up window to authenticate.

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application needs to have an identity to be able to reach the Azure Services. this credential (App Registration/Service Principal) can be provided to the application in many different way, for example via the environment variables (AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID).

Do look at the DefaultAzureCredential class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: What does this mean? So providing user account email and password in the popup window isn't enough? Do I need to register this app in the Datamart side?

Comment: To access services in Azure, your application needs to be authorized to access them. When you run it in Visual Studio, it runs under your Azure Identity (or app registration) and usually, you have access to all of Azure. But when your customers runs it, you need decide what identity the app should have, should it be in each individual users identity? and of so, do they have access to the Datamart? or should the app have its own identity? or both?

Comment: Yes each individual user has access to the Datamart. Could you please enlighten me on how to decide what identity my app has? I thought by doing Authentication=Active Directory Interactive, it will open the pop up window for each user to use their own credential (they already have access to the Datamart), but it keeps crashing instead of opening up that pop up window.

Comment: but, for external users to authenticate, I guess your app needs to have its own "app registration" so it can talk to EntraID to get the necessary access tokens (exchanged using OpenIDConnect) on behalf of the users. You can get some clues about your apps identity from the environemnt variables passed to your appliucation.  The DefaultAzureCredentials class does a lot of magic to get the app credentials.

Comment: ah I see, I guess I need to register the app on Datamart side. Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you in the right direction :-)